# Criteria-based field-level security

Tags: security, field-level-security

I have two Departments who each have different sells, based on a custom object. I would like for Dept A to only see certain fields in the sells which are created in Dept B - and vice versa.

If I wanted to make the sells completely invisible to the different departments it would be straightforward Role-based Sharing Rules. But I don't want to make the records completely invisible, only certain fields. How can I go about doing this ?

Here's the scenario :

Sells object : Sells__c
Fields : FieldA, FieldB, FieldC

If a Sells__c record is created by DeptA then I want DeptB to only see FieldA and FieldB - and vice versa.

Thank you.

Comment: Field Level Security is by profile, not by record. You'd have to build two profiles, one each for Dept A and Dept B, and set security accordingly. However, this still means that A can see B's records, but only with A's available fields, which might not be what you're aiming for, which might ultimately result in the need for tons of formulas or duplicated fields.

Comment: I think he means that the same fields would be visible vice versa.  So A would see the same fields of sales from their own department that B does when looking at sales from their own department.

Comment: sfdcfox - Yes, I realize Field Level Security is by profile. And I believe you can only either completely cut off visibility to a field - or allow it. I don't believe you can make the visibility criteria-based - can you ? I updated my initial post to draw out the scenario just to make sure we're on the same page here.

Comment: @NSjonas - I updated my original post to draw out the scenario just to make sure we're all on the same page here.

Comment: I think we are... It might be possible to do something with a VF page that has 'without sharing' depending on your requirements.  This would require that you setup sharing rules on the object and cross department records wouldn't show up in the search.

Comment: @NSjonas - I don't think I follow you there. Can you please explain that further ...?

Comment: How do users of Dept A navigate to sales records from Dept B?  (what are the requirements).  I'm not sure if my solution would meet them

Comment: Dept A would just see the record and click on it. It could appear in a Sells report of view alongside any Sell record created by somebody in their own department. But once they're in the record from the other department they would only see some of the fields.

Comment: sorry, my workaround wouldn't meet your requirements

Comment: I guess one kinda or sorta solution would be to have conditional rendering in a VF page. But like I said, that's not a true solution because the different departments could still see the fields of other departments in reports and views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how many fields are involved, one solution could be to create a set of fields for each dept.
Primary fields remain:
FieldA;B;C
DeptA_FieldA;B;C
DeptB_FieldA;B;C
DeptA has read/write only to their own fields.
DeptB has read/write only to their own fields.
DeptA and DeptB no read access to each others or primary fields.
Workflow rule updates primary fields to combine them back for higher level reporting purposes.

Comment: Jenny - I think I understand what you're describing and I was thinking that as well. Essentially making separate fields = to the original ones. It basically comes down to a TON of IF workflow statements. Not a fun thing.  I guess you would have to put both of the fields in all of the reports, assuming both Depts are looking at the same reports. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Zoom_v you might find process builder easier for updating the fields.

Comment: Good point. What a pain though. Sharing Rules need to go to the field level.  I'm sure a million people have said that already.

Comment: @Zoom_v you are definitely not alone... vote it up here https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrrIAAS!

Comment: oh, and I didn't even mention that there aren't only 2 departments, more like 10. So there would have to be 10 fields made for each one in order to account for each department's viewing rights. Fun stuff.